# What is the function to add a link to a graphic in javascript under document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, graphics, href

I am setting up a timeline using examples from http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Example.  Can someone tell me what I need to add a local link to the graphic I have?

I have tried a.href, but maybe I am doing something wrong.  Here is a snippet with my code commented out:

```
var item5 = document.createElement('div');
  item5.appendChild(document.createTextNode('item 5'));
  item5.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  var img5 = document.createElement('img');
  // img5.a.href = 'attachments/AddDuties.pdf';
  img5.src = 'icons/pdf1.png';
  img5.style.width = '48px';
  img5.style.height = '48px';
  item5.appendChild(img5);
```

Here is the some more code (I cut parts out to reduce size, it works before I add my own code below on image 5:).  Image 5 is the one I want link the graphic to a file.

```
  <title>Timeline | Basic demo</title>
  <script src="vis-4.21.0/dist/vis.js"></script>
  <link href="vis-4.21.0/dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>'
<script>
  // create a couple of HTML items in various ways

  var item1 = document.createElement('div');
  item1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('item 1'));

  var item4 = 'item <span class="large">4</span>';

  **var item5 = document.createElement('div');
  item5.appendChild(document.createTextNode('item 5'));
  item5.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  var img5 = document.createElement('img');
  // img5.a.href = 'attachments/AddDuties.pdf';
  img5.src = 'icons/pdf1.png';
  img5.style.width = '48px';
  img5.style.height = '48px';
  item5.appendChild(img5);**

</body>
```

I expect to be able to click the graphic and follow the assigned link.  I know how to use href in HTML, I just dont know what code needs to tell javascript how to link the graphic in image 5.

Comment: What happened when you tried a href?

Answer (score 0):

href is an attribute for the `<a>` tag. you can't add href to an image.
What you should do is create an `<a>` element assign the href you want to it and
append the img as a child of that `<a>` element.

```
<a href="{whatever you want}">
    <img src=....>
</a>
```

edit:
if for some reason you can't wrap the image with an `<a>` you could assign and `id` to the image and then add an event listener for a click that will redirect you.

Comment: Thanks.  I do understand how to use the href tag, but in the code above is seems like it should have a line by itself such as `` img5.a.href = 'attachments/DallasAddDuties.pdf';      but this didnt work.  If I can use code like you have, where does it go in my code?

Comment: before `item5.appendChild(img5);**` you could try creating an `a` element, say `a5` assigning an `href` to it. appending `img5` to that new `a5` element and appending `a5` to `item5`.